# Deleteing sub-strings from a file by crossing them with another file

Tags: sed, diff, large-files

N00b question: I have two files, both have only lower-letter lines and are sorted alphabetically. "file_A" has more than 11.000.000 lines of 6-7 characters and "file_B" has around 400.000 lines having 3-4 characters.

I would like to delete all lines from "file_A" if they can be partially found against lines from "file_B" ( ex: delete line "bobcat" or "catwoman" from "file_A" if is checked against line "cat" from "file_B" ). Right now, I can do it using a simple script:

```
while read -r line; do
    sed -i "/"$line"/d" $file_A
done < $file_B
```

The problem is that the process is way way way too slow (or that is how I perceive it). It looks like it takes a while until temporary saves the file_A in the same folder and checks it again, I assume - against the next string from file_B. After 6 hours I canceled it. Is it any way to make this process faster?

I searched the forum for an answer to suit. If this question was already asked, please redirect me to the answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -vFf a.txt b.txt > b.modified.txt
mv b.modified.txt > b.txt
```

- `-v` matches only lines that does match one of the patterns. This effectively removes lines that does match one of the patterns
- `-F` uses fixed strings instead of regular expressions
- `-f a.txt` read patterns from `a.txt`